# Performance when converting Results to Array

Tags: swift, realm

I’m investigating some memory/performance issues on my application and a specific usage with large amount of data.
I’m trying to understand where the bottleneck is and thought about something that is largely done in the project right now.

In several places on the app, we are converting a Results to a [T] with Array(results).
Is this a bad pattern? Should be avoided?

I noticed that Results implements LazyCollectionProtocol protocol, which allow it to be passed as the argument for the array constructor, but I don’t know what the implementation will do, will this continue being lazy as Results is?

Comment: In general, it's best not to optimize before you profile. Using the Time Profiler template in Xcode Instruments, you should be able to see the specific cause(s) of your bottleneck rather than guessing.

Comment: No, it's not a 'bad' pattern, although we don't know why you're doing that. Additionally results work very much like an array so many times there's no reason to covert it and you get the added benefit of updates to your data. Without seeing your code and undestanding the use case, there's really no way to answer the question (accurately). Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Update your question and we'll take a look.